# Projection of 25x375 to 30x375 matrix using fully connected layer

Tags: matlab, neural-network, conv-neural-network

In matlab I am implementing a convolutional neural network described in this paper
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322514744_On_the_improvement_of_classifying_EEG_recordings_using_neural_networks

The first layer projects a 25x375 matrix to 30x375 using a fully connected layer.
They do this by applying a fully connected layer of size 30 to each column.
I am trying to implement the network in Matlab, and the problem is that matlab does not support this fully connected layer projection. However i read that for every fully connected layer a convolutional layer that has an equivalent forward function exists.

How would this convolutional layer look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it using `2D convolution`.

- The `kernel` needs to be of size `(25, 1)`, so this will make it as a fully connected layer.
- For applying at each column you need to have a stride `(25, 1)`.
- The output channel needs to be `30`

The code:

```
X = tf.random_normal([25, 375])
conv = tf.transpose(tf.squeeze(tf.layers.conv2d(X[tf.newaxis, ..., tf.newaxis],
           filters=30,kernel_size=(25,1), strides=(25,1),padding='SAME')), [1,0])

print(conv.get_shape().as_list())
```

Output:

```
[30, 375]
```

Comment: Thank you, something similar can be achieved in matlab, so this is very helpful.